# Using a single handleInputChange method to for multiple input fields (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, react-native, react-redux

I have a form, in React"

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
          <input
            value={this.state.first}
          />

          <input
            value={this.state.second}
          />

          <input
            value={this.state.third}
          />
           //.... many more
        </form>
     //...
)}
```

My `handleInputChange` usually looks like this:

```
  handleInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value });
  }
```

Now, since I have many different input fields, i would normally do many different `handleInputChange` methods. However, all of these handle input change things basically do the same: they set the state anew, according to which input field is currently edited.

How could I, instead of writing three `handleInputChange` methods each doing something like:

```
  handleInputChangeFirst(e) {
    this.setState({first: e.target.value });
  }
  handleInputChangeSecond(e) {
    this.setState({second: e.target.value });
  }
```

... do all of this with one single `handleInputChange`, which then checks which value needs to be updated? How can i let `handleInputChange` know about the input field that is being edited and react accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a generic `handleInputChange` method:

```
handleInputChange(property) {
  return e => {
    this.setState({
      [property]: e.target.value
    });
  };
}
```

That you’d use as such:

```
<input
  value={this.state.first}
  onChange={this.handleInputChange('first')}
/>
```

Comment: would i not give my `handleInputChange` the event anymore then?

Comment: this `handleInputChange` returns a function that does take the event as sole argument. it's basically a factory for handlers.

Comment: interesting! Why would I have to change it this way, or why did you decide to do so?

Comment: I’m not saying that you have to change it this way :) but this does answer your issue doesn’t it? with this you only have one function that works for multiple fields.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't the above method return a new function for each render? So if you pass these handlers down to a child component then they'd be seen as an updated prop every time instead of the same prop (cause it's a new function every render), and cause an unwanted re-render of the child. One of the reasons inline functions are hated in the render method.

Here's another solution I saw somewhere online:

```
handleInputChange = event => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  this.setState({
    [name]: value
  });
}
```

And the input element:

```
<input name="first" value={this.state.first} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
```

Name might not be the best attribute to use, but you get the point